# XML-Serialization - How to pass an property-array without it loosing its XML-Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have two classes. One of the classes is containing an array of the other class.

I dont want the first Class to be serialized, only the array of the other class, so I am passing the array to the Serialization-Method, but it seems to be loosing its name, as it is later called ArrayOfSecondClass. Can someone help me with this?

Here is some Test-Code describing the Scenario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TeaTimeTestEmpty
{
    public class FirstClass
    {
        [XmlArray("RealName")] // Is ignored when SecondClassArray is passed
        public SecondClass[] SecondClassArray { get; set; }
    }
    public class SecondClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Program
    {
        public static string SerializeToXml(object objectToSerialize, Type objectType = null)
        {
            if (objectToSerialize != null)
            {
                if (objectType == null)
                {
                    objectType = objectToSerialize.GetType();
                }
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);

                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize, null);

                    string xmlString = "";
                    foreach (byte currentByte in stream.ToArray())
                    {
                        xmlString += (char)currentByte;
                    }

                    return xmlString;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SecondClass> listOfSecondClasses = new List<SecondClass>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                listOfSecondClasses.Add(new SecondClass() { Name = "Bob" + i });
            }

            FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass() { SecondClassArray = listOfSecondClasses.ToArray()};

            // Note that I am passing only the SecondClassArray, not the whole Element
            string xml = SerializeToXml(firstClass.SecondClassArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I am debugging this, I get the following XML-Code in the variable xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSecondClass 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob0</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob1</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob2</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob3</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob4</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob5</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob6</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob7</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob8</Name>
  </SecondClass>
  <SecondClass>
    <Name>Bob9</Name>
  </SecondClass>
</ArrayOfSecondClass>
```

My problem now is, that the Name I gave it in FirstClass is lost, and I cant seem to find a way to get it back, not even if I am giving the SecondClass XmlRoot or other tags, it is always calling it ArrayOfSecondClass instead of the wanted name.

I would appreciate it if you could give me a solution to how to give it the name I want it to have.

Comment: You need to have "RealName" in your output, correct?

Comment: Yes, it should say <RealName>...</Realname> instead of <ArrayOfSecondClass>...</...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<SecondClass> listOfSecondClasses = new List<SecondClass>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        listOfSecondClasses.Add(new SecondClass() { Name = "Bob" + i });
    }

    FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass() { SecondClassArray = listOfSecondClasses.ToArray() };

    // Note that I am passing only the SecondClassArray, not the whole Element
    string xml = SerializeToXml(firstClass.SecondClassArray,"RealNames");

    Console.WriteLine(xml);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string SerializeToXml<T>(T objectToSerialize, string RootNodeName)
{
    if (objectToSerialize != null)
    {

        XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute(RootNodeName);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),root);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize, null);

            string xmlString = "";
            foreach (byte currentByte in stream.ToArray())
            {
        xmlString += (char)currentByte;
            }

            return xmlString;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, greatly explained.

Comment: @Garaug Dave Would you mind upvoting my question? I am currently on QuestionBan because of past Questions

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlArray` attribute is part of `FirstClass` not of its property, so it is clear that it is not used when the serializer never sees an instance of `FirstClass`.

You will need to work with [another constructor of the `XmlSerializer` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1wczcys(v=vs.110).aspx).

This constructor allows you to pass the name of the root element:

```
XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "RealName";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType, xRoot);
```

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my question? I am currently on QuestionBan because of past Questions

Comment: @BotMaster3000: Asking for upvotes is not the way to go. It might even result in more severe consequences. If you are on question ban, then that's for a reason. You might try and remove those offending questions.

Comment: I am sorry, but this question should have been good enough to get me out of the ban, it is the first question after the ban, and since it didnt get a single upvote it seems that the ban was active again..

Comment: Well, it's not a great question. It could have been more to the point